# Cannot download a publicly available file on government website using .net framework

Tags: ssl

For over a year my Azure function has successfully downloaded a publicly available file using .net framework version 4.72 WebClient.DownloadFile() setting protocol to TLS 1.2.  The client can no longer establish a secure TLS channel.  I upgraded from .net 4.72 to 4.80 and set client protocol to TLS 1.3.  Now the error is server & client don't have common algorithm.  I tried HttpClient and get identical errors.  The files are located at https://cops.fas.gsa.gov/awards/ and I can manually download using Chrome or Firefox.

''''
private bool DownloadGovFile(/*string url, string fileName*/)
{
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13; // | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ;
//ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
//ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

```
        string errMsg = string.Empty;
        bool bRC;

        string url = "https://cops.fas.gsa.gov/awards/awards_2021.csv";            
        string fileName = @"c:\tmp\awards_2021.csv";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                //client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36");
                //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
            }

            bRC = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bRC = false;
            errMsg = string.Format("ContractsUpdater::DownloadContractFile - Exception attempting to download from url [{0}].  Attempting to write to file [{1}].  EX: [{2}]", url, fileName, ex.ToString());
        }

        if (bRC)
            MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(errMsg);

        return bRC;

    }
```

''''

Comment: some code might help indicate the issue

Comment: "Now the error is server & client don't have common algorithm." So you have your answer in your question. If you force a specific version at the client that the server does not speak, of course it won't work, by design. So why not letting them autonegotiate the highest version, as it happens normally?

Comment: Auto negotiating never worked on this server and still does not.  But it worked over a year by setting protocol to v1.2 and v1.1 (bitwise or). I tried forcing v1.2, v1.3, and both (bitwise or).  I used SSS Labs and see server supports v1.2 & v1.3 and nothing wrong between the supported algorithms on my win10 machine and server.  The day the problem started it quit working on both my machine as well as Microsoft's Azure environment.